# Allowing a user to update the contents of an app

Tags: android, ios

I just want to start by saying I am doing this for a friend as a general information app and I am receiving no money for doing this. He would like an app to help inform his clients of different treatments as well as adding in daily memos etc. I can create an app no problem and have only created apps for general use and for my University assignments (I will also add that this is not a university project but just more to improve my own abilities). I am hoping someone may have a suggestion for how I can allow my friend to update the apps information easily. For example, I will be creating a general app that will display information (contact information, advice, guidelines, exercises etc) most of which will need updated every so often. He has also said he would like to add a daily update (almost like a daily tip or piece of advice). What I would really like help with, is for guidance on how I can have my friend maintain the app after I have done the project. I want an easy way for him to add/remove/edit memos or information. I haven't come across anything like this so I don't know if it is possible or if it is possible but complex etc. I hope I have explained the scenario well enough. Only looking guidelines of things I can research and do on my own, I just don't know where to start looking.

Comment: You will need to host the content on a server somewhere and provide some method for your friend to update the content. Then your app can retrieve the information from the server

Comment: This is way too broad for here, but I'm going to give you some advice-  I wouldn't take this project if I were you.  I don't know his full requirements-  but neither do you.  You aren't being paid.  You're a beginner.  You have no supervision, and haven't worked on a project of real scope before.  TO get something that works shittily will take you a few hundred hours.  YOur friend will be pissed at how long it takes and low quality it is.  You'll be pissed at how much effort it takes, put up with a lot of stress, and have time crunches.  Its a great way to ruin a friendship.

Comment: If you are going to ignore my advice and take it-  do this as a formal project.  Start with requirements gathering, build out a project plan, estimate the time needed for each part, and make sure both of you understand how much effort everything is going to be.  Because right now you're about to dive in way over your head.

Comment: Thanks for the advice guys, will meet up with him again and do something for him that is within my skill level for the time being and forget about the updates and things. He's not overly fussed on having an app but at the same time he said he'd like to see what it would be like to have one. Will stick to creating a general information app such as his business location, contact details and general tips and guidelines. It's something I can do no problem and it's just something to give him an idea of whether or not he'd like to pay a professional to fully develop an app for him or not. Thanks